# RefineryCMS , undefined method `persisted?' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, refinerycms

I'm having some problems figuring out what is this problem. It only happens in a child page.

```
1: <%= form_for [refinery, :admin, @page],
2:              :url => (refinery.admin_page_path(@page.uncached_nested_url) if @page.persisted?) do |f| %>

4:   <%= render '/refinery/admin/error_messages', :object => @page, :include_object_name => true %>
```

The information I have found in google sends me to 404 pages in github so I don't know how to resolve this issue.

Thank you for your time

Comment: Do you have the i18n plugin installed?